# how to show confirm when sort in mat-table angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular 8 with angular material 8, i want to show confirm when sort on mat-table.
if user confirm true icon will change and when confirm false false icon not change.
how can i do it?? please help to resolve this issue
[stack-blitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5wzsk?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.html)

Comment: you can remove the directive sort and implement custom sort by calling the sortData method of this class https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your requirement is to require the user to confirm the sort before calling the function to sort the data.

If so, you have two options:

- Create a custom directive to handle the sort "manually";
- Save the *last* sort event to possibly "rollback" operation if user cancels it.

---

Here's an example for the 2nd. approach:

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class TableSortingExample {
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  lastSort: Partial<Sort> = {};

  sortChangeHandler(evt: Sort): void {
    if (confirm('Confirm question?')) {
      this.lastSort = {
        active: this.sort.active,
        direction: this.sort.direction
      };
      // Perform sort operation
    } else {
      this.sort.active = this.lastSort.active;
      this.sort.direction = this.lastSort.direction;
    }
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**FULL DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5wzsk-1iqpaw)</kbd>